# NodeJS remove appended data from file

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is how I append data to a file:

```
self.fs.appendFile(targetFilePath, new Buffer(sourceData, 'base64'), function(err) { ... });
```

How can I remove data from a file that have been appended? This is required if the stream I receive earlier is interrupted and parts have been written.

Is it possible to undo the last append command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't undo anything.

You can [truncate](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_truncatesync_path_len) the file to a known point (length...):

```
self.fs.truncateSync(targetFilePath, somePoint);
```

Or you could originally not write what you're unsure of, just aggregate to memory or a temporary file until you're certain.

Comment: this would remove the data at the given length to the end of the file, right?

Comment: That's right. Just make sure the file isn't locked.